# NPM package for getting flat dependencies array from a NPM package directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to programmatically, via Node.js, get a flat array instead of a dependency tree; e.g.:

```
["bar@18.15.5", "qux@1.0.0", "baz@0.9.3"]
```

In ascending dependency order, e.g.: if `y` relies on `x`, then `x` is the first package in the array:

- `x@0.1.0`
- `y@0.1.0`

Is there a NPM package for this? E.g.:

```
// path/to/package contains a package.json and node_modules
let deps = getDependencies('path/to/package');
```